# Array of form elements - groupping radio buttons

Tags: html

My web form contains a row with the following text and radio elements:

```
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M"> M
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F"> F
```

Now I'd like to create this form with multiple such a rows so I'll need to use array of form elements. For text element I will use:

```
  <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
```

But what to do with radio elements (they're already an array). I cannot just make

```
  <input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="M"> M
  <input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="F"> F
```

because index of second element will be incremented and this would separate two radio buttons from the same group. I cannot do this either:

```
  <input type="radio" name="gender[][]" value="M"> M
  <input type="radio" name="gender[][]" value="F"> F
```

So, what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use an array, like this:

```
<!-- First Group -->
<input type="radio" name="gender[0]" value="M"> M
<input type="radio" name="gender[0]" value="F"> F

<!-- Second Group -->
<input type="radio" name="gender[1]" value="M"> M
<input type="radio" name="gender[1]" value="F"> F

<!-- Third Group -->
<input type="radio" name="gender[2]" value="M"> M
<input type="radio" name="gender[2]" value="F"> F
```

You just have to keep track of the array's index.

Comment: Ok, that's right but I created rows in foreach loop so there's no explicit incrementor. I will introduce it if there's no other solution. I thought there was a simpler solution with implicit incrementor like with name[].

Comment: What language are you using for the server-side code? Can you post your code in the question?

Comment: I use PHP, but how does it matter? and for what purpose to post this code (that's just regular foreach(){} loop where I will introduce $i++ incrementor for indexing form elements).